# Alternative to setting database connection from file

Tags: c#, web-services, connection-string

I have a web service which invokes 2 different web methods.

One of the methods uses a `SQL` server connection and the other uses `DB2`.

The ODBC connection can talk to both a DB2 database and SQL server however the SQL has to be designed slightly differently for each method hence the option to switch the connection.

Right now I have a solution in place that is reading a string value from a text file stored on the server.

So if the string is SQL it uses the SQL connection string and ODBC uses the ODBC connection string.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, without having to read the file in every time a web method is called as I am concerned that in the live environment, there will be bulk loads of data getting sent. So my concern is in the speed and performance of using this method.

Example of how I have implemented this -

```
String DBconSQL = "SQL-connection-string";
String DBconODBC = "ODBC-connection-string";       
string connection = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"filePath");


    [WebMethod]
    public string stringRETURN(string connection)
    {
        if(connection == "SQL")
        {
        string con = "DBconSQL";
        string sql = "SQL"

        }
        if(connection == "ODBC")
        {
            con = DBconODBC;
            sql = "ODBC SQL";

        }

              //Do stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just store the value of each in memory after the first file read or just store them in the code.

i.e.

```
static class Globals
{
    public static string DB2ConnStr = String.Empty;
    public static string MSSQLStr = String.Empty;
}
```

You can read and write these from anywhere and they will persist as long as the server is up (i.e. the app is running in an app domain)

You should also (hopefully) be aware of the security concerns of storing plain text credentials either in code or text docs and (if this is for production) provide some form of encryption / security / reduce user permissions of the account that is being used to access the database ;)

Comment: How would I store it in memory after the first file read and also what would happen if the file changed? I have taken into consideration the security flaws with this method.

Comment: Changing the variable based on when a file is changed is a bit more difficult but not overly - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: So if I set these as globals like in you example, this would save the string to memory and would not have to read the file everytime? Also what happens when the text value of the file changes?

Comment: see last comment about FileSystemWatcher and yes, static variables on a static class are basically global, system wide memory storage (the static class is initialised on system start and is held in memory for the lifetime of the dll